# HttpURLConnection freezes when calling getResponseCode, getContentLength

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, httpurlconnection

I am writing a simple java program to connect to a server with tomcat6 installed. The problem is, when I use the following code to access the .mp4 files at the server, it is fine if I access 1.mp4 but when I access other files(2.mp4,3.mp4 and so on), it usually takes about two minutes to do getResponseCode() and getContentLength(). Some times longer.  The code at the client is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  String urlText =  "http://some_http_address:some_port/1.mp4";

  URL url = new URL(urlText);
  HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  System.out.println("opConnection " + (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000 + "s ");

  int code = huc.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println("Code: " + code + " " + (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000 + "s ");

  int size = huc.getContentLength(); 
  System.out.println("Size: " + size + " " + (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000 + "s ");

  InputStream in = (InputStream) huc.getContent();
  System.out.println("Start to copy " + (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000 + "s ");

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/some/path/temp/temp.mp4");//destinationfile

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len1 = 0;
  if(in != null){
     while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       fos.write(buffer,0, len1);   
     }
  }

  if(fos != null){
      fos.close();
  }

  huc.disconnect();
  System.out.println("Copy done " + (double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000 + "s " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

A typical output for the unlucky files is:

```
opConnection 0.007s 
Code: 200 279.565s 
Size: 10246547 279.565s 
Start to copy 279.57s 
Copy done 297.258s 1392356076554
```

When I try to collect data, it is about 279 seconds... Far more than the usually 120 seconds...

And a typical output for the luck 1.mp4 is:

```
opConnection 0.004s 
Code: 200 0.107s 
Size: 24448266 0.107s 
Start to copy 0.113s 
Copy done 32.1s 1392355716952
```

All file are small, less than 25 MB, and are located at /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT. The server uses the default servlet. Part of the conf/web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

It is weird that getResponseCode is so slow. In the case above, getContentLength only took a small amount of time but if I execute if without getResponseCode before it, it also takes a very long time to get the size. What is more weird, it only happens to files other than 1.mp4! It never happens to 1.mp4.

I am totally confused about this, does any one have any idea?

---------------------------------------------Update 1---------------------------------------------

As suggested, I move `huc.getResponseCode()` and `huc.getResponseCode()` after the copy is done, restart tomcat at the server, add `in.close()` before `huc.disconnect()`, the same thing happened: 119s freeze before `huc.getInputStream()`, 15s for copy, but only 1ms to get response code and content length. Seems that it needs more than 2 minutes before any operation to `HttpURLConnection huc` and after that everything is fine. Any ideas?

Thank you guys in advance.

---------------------------------------------Update 2---------------------------------------------
The problem just went away when I came to my office. I still don't know what caused it. I guess it would be something related to the network connection since the server is at the first floor of my office. I would post more updates if I got them.

Comment: I think I met same problem here... is it really about the network? I am asking because my code is running on single node... odd.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
InputStream in = huc.getInputStream();
```

instead of

```
InputStream in = (InputStream) huc.getContent();
```

Regarding `getContentLength()` and `getResponseCode()`, apparently they download the whole file before returning back.

**UPD**

Comments showed that there is an issue with connecting to the server.
Try to call

```
 in.close();
```

before

```
 huc.disconnect();
```

And restart Tomcat or wait for some time before next tries.

Comment: I think the download speed is reasonable, 10 seconds for 10 MB and 32 seconds for 24 MB so nothing to do with the InputStream. But even if getContentLength() and getResponseCode() download the whole file, it is weird to take almost 5 mins. Moreover, why it only takes 0.107s for 1.mp4 but 279.565s for 2.mp4? It is reproducible so I do think it is because of the quality of connection.

Comment: For some reason, lucky 1.mp4 is not downloaded on `getContentLength()/getResponseCode()`. I found topics on the web about similar issues with low speed `getContentLength()/getResponseCode()` for mobile devices. Are you running the client on mobile? Anyway, try to download the file first then call other methods.

Comment: I am running on my laptop. But before that I face the same problem on my smartphone so that's why I try to test on my laptop.(But the same code works fine then the slow issue occurs this afternoon) I tried what you said, but the unlucky files are still unlucky. I put huc.getInputStream() right after url.openConnection but it still freezes before huc.getInputStream() for 287s, and then 15s for copy to be done. So I cannot believe it is because getContentLength() and `getResponseCode()` download everything before return.

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I added `in.close()` right before `huc.disconnect()`, restart Tomcat, the problem is still there. 119s before `InputStream in = huc.getInputStream()` and 15s for copy process. Any new idea? I am going crazy about this issue.

Comment: Heh.. I would add more logging to Tomcat then to see when it accepts connection, etc.